# Android's expanded BottomSheetDialogFragment offset distance to start collapsing

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

I use BottomSheetDialogFragment expanded to full screen. Does anyone know how to make it get back expanded if a user has dragged & dropped it before a predefined distance reached? So I mean a BottomSheet should restore full expanded state if it hasn't been dragged over the long enough distance. Now it seems the default distance is 0 and the expanded BottomSheet can be closed occasionally on internal scroll in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I've found the following solution:

```
open class CustomBottomSheetBehavior<V : View?>(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : BottomSheetBehavior<V>(context, attrs) {

    var offsetToCollapse: Int = 220 // this is bottom sheet's collapsing threshold offset

    private val lastNestedScrollDyField by lazy { ReflectionUtils.getField(BottomSheetBehavior::class.java, "lastNestedScrollDy") }

    override fun shouldHide(child: View, yvel: Float): Boolean {
        if (0 < offsetToCollapse && offsetToCollapse > child.top) {
            ReflectionUtils.setFieldValue(this, lastNestedScrollDyField, 0)
            return false
        }
        return super.shouldHide(child, yvel)
    }
}


object ReflectionUtils {

    fun <T> getField(clazz: Class<T>?, fieldName: String?): Field? {
        if (clazz == null || fieldName == null) return null
        try {
            return clazz.getDeclaredField(fieldName)
        } catch (e: NoSuchFieldException) {
            Timber.e(e)
        }
        return null
    }

    fun setFieldValue(any: Any?, field: Field?, value: Any?) {
        if (any == null || field == null) return
        try {
            field.isAccessible = true
            field[any] = value
        } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
            Timber.e(e)
        }
    }
}
```

And don't forget to put this into proguard-rules.pro:

```
-keepclassmembers class com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior {
    private <fields>;
}
```